# how do I redirect a url and remove part of the string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect

I have an url like this:

```
domain.com/thispart/blah-something-blah-remove
```

I need to redirect this url like this:

```
domain.com/newpart/blah-something-blah
```

change the directory and remove the last part(the last part is always constant, this time it's remove).

How do I do this? I managed to redirect the directory, but the last par I don't know how to remove.

Comment: You should show what you have tried - it may just require a simple fix. Also, do you have any other directives in your `.htacess` file? The order (and type) of these directives is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you don't have any existing mod_rewrite directives then you can do something like the following using a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch ^/thispart/([\w-]+)-remove$ /newpart/$1
```

Note that this removes "-remove", as in your example, not simply the string "remove".

The path segment before the "-remove" part is assumed to consist of the characters `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_` or `-`.

This is a temporary (302) redirect.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

---

However, if you have existing mod_rewrite directives then you should use mod_rewrite instead to avoid potential conflicts (and improve efficiency). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^thispart/([\w-]+)-remove$ /newpart/$1 [R=302,L]
```

(Note the absence of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.)